# Wait for async data from another mobx store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, mobx

I have 2 stores: UserStore and TodoStore.
For fetching the todos i need to know the ID of my logged in user.

That's part of my UserStore

```
export default class UserStore {
  @observable currentUser = null;
  @observable loading = false;

  constructor() {
    this.subscribe();
  }

  @action subscribe = () => {
    this.loading = true;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user) {
        this.setCurrentUser(user);
      } else {
        this.unsetCurrentUser();
      }
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }
}
```

and this is the constructor of my TodoStore

```
constructor(users) {
    this.users = users;

    console.log(this.users.currentUser) //null

    this.storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('files/todos');
    this.todosRef = firebase.database().ref(`todos/${this.users.currentUser.uid}`);
    this.filesRef = firebase.database().ref(`files/${this.users.currentUser.uid}/todos`);

    this.logger();
  }
```

The problem here is that I am getting an error because at the moment of calling this the currentUser is still null.

This is how i combine my stores:

```
const routing = new RouterStore();
const ui = new UiStore();
const users = new UserStore(ui);
const todos = new TodoStore(users);

const stores = {
  routing,
  ui,
  users,
  todos,
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I know when the currentUser observable is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is this case would be to save a reference to the firebase auth promise in the user store, and use the `currentUser` in the `TodoStore` once it has resolved:

```
// UserStore.js
export default class UserStore {
  @observable currentUser = null;
  @observable loading = false;
  authPromise = null;

  constructor() {
    this.subscribe();
  }

  @action subscribe = () => {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authPromise = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user) {
        this.currentUser = user;
      } else {
        this.currentUser = null;
      }
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }
}

// TodoStore.js
export default class TodoStore {
  constructor(userStore) {
    this.userStore = userStore;
    userStore.authPromise.then(() => {
      const uid = userStore.currentUser.uid;
      this.storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('files/todos');
      this.todosRef = firebase.database().ref(`todos/${uid}`);
      this.filesRef = firebase.database().ref(`files/${uid}/todos`);
      this.logger();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: oh yeah! thanks! why didnt i figure this out myself :D